# Background fullscreen video position: top center

Tags: html, css

I try to put a video on my website. It should always cover the whole screen. Its no problem if the video gets cut on the sides or the bottom. The most important part of the video is in the top middle. 
I've already found a code that works pretty well if you want that the video's center is always visible. But I want the top (and middle) to be visible.

Here is my current code.

```css
.vidwrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    overflow: hidden;
}



video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 
    <div class="vidwrap">
        <video autobuffer="" autoplay="">
            <source src="video/background-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
   </div>
```

And in this code the top stays visible but its not aligned in the center anymore:

```css
.vidwrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:  blue;
}



video {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
```

```html
   
    <div class="vidwrap">
        <video autobuffer="" autoplay="">
            <source src="video/background-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    
    </div>
```

I am not able to bring these codes together. Can you help me?

Comment: try using Flexbox...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the top be always visible anyways?

Comment: In my first code the top and the bottom get cut out if i change the window size. So the middle keeps visible.

Comment: This website has a background video with the functions I'd like to have. But its not full screen. 
[link](https://vimeo.com/de/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.vidwrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #00f;
}



video {
      min-height: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-0);
}
```

```html
<div class="vidwrap">
        <video autobuffer="" autoplay="">
            <source src="https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped me to find the right solution!

Answer (score -1):

For everyone who is looking for the answer. My code seems to work perfectly now (at least it does what I want it to do :D)

This is my code now after nidhi's help

```css
.vidwrap {
    position: absolute;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 
video {
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-0);
}
```

```html
<div class="vidwrap">
        <video autobuffer="" autoplay="">
            <source src="video/background-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    
</div>
```

Thank you!